# Eclipse Hibernate tools not working anymore after DB switch

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, hibernate-tools

I am using hibernate tools with eclipse, and it was working fine, till I've changed my DB. I've configured the new database, run the test cases and every thing is fine, except for hibernate tools. The Hibernate console isn't fetching tables from DB nor throws it any exception. I entered the configuration manually and by clicking test connection, the test ping succeeds, but still when trying to create a new rev eng file, no tables are shown, could you please help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a workaround than a real solution but if editing the existing configuration didn't work (and it should definitely work), then I suggest creating a new one.

Comment: i created a new wrkspc and then creating new console configuration manually, it's working fine, but changing my configuration file (hibernate.cfg.hbm) in my old wrkspc isn't working, btw you said it shouldn't be working, why?

Comment: @Amr No, what I meant is that editing the existing configuration should work.

Comment: i think it may be a plug-in bug, as it's working when creating new wrkspc with new project !!!!, thanks for your help